# copy props from obj to obj in a functional Programming way

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, copy

I've got these Interfaces:

```
  export interface QueryObject {
    id: ID;
    path: string[];
    filters: Filters;
  }

  export interface Filters {
    state: string;
    localeID: string;
    role: string;
  }
```

And trying to come up with a Functional Programming solution in order to just copy the properties that exist and have a value from a tmp object to the existing data model. Now,.. obviously this doesnt work. `Filters` will be completely overwritten while losing the properties `localeID` and `role`.

```
  let queryObject: QueryObject;
  let filters: Filters = { state: 'GB'}; // this obviously gives an error on Interface implementation
  queryObject.filters = filters;
```

Right now I'am taking the original object, traversing to the property and overwriting it with the updated value.

```
  const queryObject: QueryObject = _.cloneDeep(this.queryObject);
  queryObject.filters.state = state; // 'GB'
  this.portareService.update(queryObject, this.portareQuery.getActiveId());
```

Would be nice to solve this with a Object.assign or spread `...` solution like:

```
{
  return ...createQueryObject, updatedQueryObject
}
```

I know how to do this with a function using loop(s), but looking for a Functional Programming approach to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a `concat` method for both `QueryObject` and `Filters`. In the `concat`, you define what "merge logic" you want to use. The `QueryObject` calls the `Filters`' concat method internally.

Within the `concat` methods, you can use the spread syntax or any other logic to ensure new objects are created and you're not mutating anything.

By adding an `empty` constructor, you can easily start using those concatenators inside a `reduce` or other automated merge.

I found [this blog post on Semigroups by Tom Harding](http://www.tomharding.me/2017/03/13/fantas-eel-and-specification-4/) super inspiring. [This post about Monoids](http://www.tomharding.me/2017/03/21/fantas-eel-and-specification-5/) has some info about the `empty` part in it.

```js
const QueryObject = ({id = null, path = null, filters = Filters.empty() })=> ({ 
  id, 
  path,
  filters,

  concat: other => QueryObject({
    id: other.id || id,
    path: other.path || path,
    filters: filters.concat(other.filters)
  }),
  
  toString: () => `QueryObject(${id}, ${path}, ${filters.toString()})`
});

QueryObject.empty = () => QueryObject({});
QueryObject.merge = (x, y) => x.concat(y);
  


const Filters = ({ state = null, localeID = null, role = null }) => ({
  state,
  localeID,
  role,
  
  concat: other => Filters({
    state: other.state || state,
    localeID: other.localeID || localeID,
    role: other.role || role
  }),
  
  toString: () => `Filters(${state}, ${localeID}, ${role})`
});
  
Filters.empty = () => Filters({});
Filters.merge = (x, y) => x.concat(y);


const userFilter = Filters({ role: "User" });
const gbFilter = Filters({ localeID: "GB" });

const filterSettings = [userFilter, gbFilter];
const mergedFilter = filterSettings.reduce(Filters.merge, Filters.empty());

console.log(
  "Merged Filter:",
  mergedFilter.toString()
);

// Some base query
const accountQuery = QueryObject({ id: "CUSTOM_Q_1", path: "/accounts" });

// Derived queries
const userQuery = accountQuery.concat(QueryObject({ filters: userFilter }));
const gbQuery = accountQuery.concat(QueryObject({ filters: gbFilter }));

console.log(
  "User Query:",
  userQuery.toString()
);

console.log(
  "Brittish Users Query",
  userQuery.concat(gbQuery).toString()
);
```

Edit:
Of course, without the "theory", there's also the more generic:

```js
const uniques = xs => Array.from(new Set(xs));

const nullMergeStrategy = (obj1, obj2) => 
  uniques(
    Object.keys(obj1)
          .concat(Object.keys(obj2))
  ).reduce(
    (acc, k) => Object.assign(acc, { [k]: obj2[k] || obj1[k] }),
    {}
  );


const Filter = ({ state = null, localeID = null, role = null }) =>
  ({ state, localeID, role });
  
const userFilter = Filter({ role: "User" });
const gbFilter = Filter({ localeID: "GB" });

console.log(
  nullMergeStrategy(userFilter, gbFilter)
)
```

Comment: Appreciate this extensive answer and snippet! So I guess there is no Functional shorthand approach? ;-) This stuff is fascinating, the hyperlinks and all.

Comment: I added an example of a more generic `nullMerge` strategy that you could use as a utility. I prefer the more specific approach though :)